# javascript google map v3 and data property missing

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Trying to load a geojson result into my google map.  According to the documentation ("Every Map has a Data object by default, so most of the time there is no need to construct one.") I can just do map.data.loadGeoJson.  The problem is that there is no data property on map.  So I tried to just create on by doing google.maps.Data().  Again Data is not a recognized type.  This comes from documentation of version 3.16.  Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?  this is the url I use to reference map:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=visualization&sensor=false&language=en&v=3.16

Comment: Please post the code that you are encountering issues with.  How do you create and access the map?  Have you tried the examples in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer)?

Comment: I am using the angular-google-maps directive.  This directive gets the map in this fashion:   _m = new google.maps.Map(el.find("div")[1], angular.extend({}, DEFAULTS, opts, {
            center: this.getCoords(scope.center),
            draggable: this.isTrue(attrs.draggable),
            zoom: scope.zoom,
            bounds: scope.bounds
          }));

Comment: I set a break point in a couple places and there is no data property on the map.  In my directive I also tried it like this:  googleMap.getMap().data.  this is also undefined.  I tried just creating a Data object but that also does not exist:  new $window.google.maps.Data();

Answer (score 0):

It's a property of the `google.maps.Map`-instance:

```
var someMapInstance=new google.maps.Map(/*arguments*/);

//someMapInstance.data will be  what you are looking for
 console.log(someMapInstance.data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Now it is showing up.  I had recently changed my link from version 3.14 to 3.16 so maybe it just got stuck in cache though not sure how since the url was different but either way it is working now.